# ASP.net web application deployed to elastic beanstalk giving 500 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have ASP.net web application running good in localhost.
Then I published that application to AWS Elastic Bean Stalk.
When I opened that URL, it shows 500 Internal Server Error.
Please help me.